# AWS JavaScript resolver, Unable to convert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-sam

Trying JS resolver for the first time, Getting the Unable to convert error,

// Query-listItems-request.js

```
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils';

export function request(ctx) {
  const { args: { userId } } = ctx;

  return {
    operation: 'Query',
    query: {
      expression: '#id = :id',
      expressionValues: util.dynamodb.toMapValues({ ':id': `${userId}` }),
      expressionNames: { '#id': 'id' },
    },
  };
}

export function response(ctx) {
  return ctx.result;
}
```

AWS Sam tempalte:

```
  AppGraphqlApiQueryListBalanceLogsResolver:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      TypeName: Query
      DataSourceName: !GetAtt AppGraphqlApiToListItemDataSource.Name
      RequestMappingTemplateS3Location: Query-listItems-request.js
      ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location: AppGraphqlApi/response.vtl
      ApiId: !Ref AppGraphqlApi
      FieldName: listItems
    DependsOn: AppGraphqlBOApiSchema
```

Comment: Hi I am stuck here , did you find a fix please?

Comment: I eneded up using the non js format, this wouldn't budge

Comment: I am using Amplify project, it seems is not yet supported this feature, please check this link https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/1572 , so go  back to vtl language, no choice